# Making a controller exist on as a sub-controller, how to fix form routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `ChaptersController` that does not have a direct route (i.e. `site/chapters/:id`) but only exists as a sub route for a `BooksController` (i.e. `site/books/:id/chapters/:id`). however, when I try to go to books/:id/chapters/new , I get the following routing error:

```
Showing .../app/views/chapters/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"chapters"}
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using nested routes in this manner:

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
```

in which case you should have the named routes 'book_chapter' and 'book_chapters'.  You can check this by running `rake routes`.

In your _form.html.erb partial you need to change this line:

```
<%= form_for(@chapter) do |f|%>
```

You need to specify the target URL of the form explicitly, and probably also handle different URLs for create and update scenarios.  Try something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@chapter, :url => (@chapter.new_record? ? book_chapters_path(@book) : book_chapter_path(@book, @chapter) )) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is wrong path in /app/views/chapters/_form.html.erb

Check what url is in  tag. I suppose you forgot to change it to nested in books.

You may as well paste _form.html.erb here, so i will point it out :)